# complex analysis(introduction) - locus on Argand diagram satisfying $z^{n-1}=\bar{z}$ ($z\in\mathbb{C}, n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers, contest-math

**Question**: Determine on Argand diagram the locus in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ satisfying: $z^{n-1}= \bar{z} \space (n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\})$

**My attempt:** Let: $z:=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) (r:=|z|, \theta:=argz)$ Then:

$z^{n-1}= \bar{z} \iff r^{n-1}(\cos (n-1)\theta+i\sin(n-1)\theta)=r\cos\theta-ir\sin n \theta\iff \begin{cases}r^{n-1}\cos(n-1)\theta =r\cos\theta && (1)\\
r^{n-1}\sin(n-1)\theta=-r\sin\theta  && (2)\end{cases}$

If: $\cos(n-1)\theta \neq 0$ then: dividing $(2)$ by $(1)$ yields: $\tan(n-1)\theta=\tan(-\theta) \implies (n-1)\theta=-\theta+k\pi \space(k\in\mathbb{Z}) \implies \theta = \frac{k\pi}{n}$ In this case the locus is set of rays going from $(0,0)$ satisfying: $\theta=\frac{k\pi}{n} $($\theta$-angle between real line of Argand diagram and given ray)

If: $\cos(n-1)\theta=0$,then: 
$\begin{cases} 
r\cos(\theta)=0 && (3)\\ 
r^{n-2}\sin(n-1)\theta=-\sin\theta && (4)
\end{cases}$

$(3)$implies: $\theta=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}\space(k\in\mathbb{Z})$ implying that $(4)$ then yields: $r=1$ (since then sine functions are equal to $(-1)^{l},(-1)^{m}$, where: $l,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ but modulus of complex number is positive). In this case the locus is set of point lying on unit circle centred at $(0,0)$, where angle between real line and segment joining origin and k-th distinct point is $\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2}$

**Troubles**: My analysis is incorrect since I think that I should obtain only set of points, while at some point set of rays pops out. Besides, I intuitively feel that my reasoning is incomplete...

**Request**: Could anyone state gaps in my reasoning, please?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Do you want corrections to your method above, or a different solution to the problem?

Comment: Up to you. If you think that this problem can be solved in a different and elegant way, then I would be thankful for seeing such solution.

Comment: If you think that my solution can be rectified to yield final answer, then I would be thankful for help.

Comment: I will answer a different solution, then if I have time later I will try to correct your process.

Comment: Hint: if $n=2$ the equality $z=\bar z$ is satisfied by $\forall z \in \mathbb{R}\,$, else for $n \gt 2$ taking the modulus on both sides gives $|z|^{n-1}=|\bar z|=|z|$ $\implies$ $|z|=0$ or $|z|=1$. In the latter case, multiplying by $z$ gives $z^n=|z|^2=1\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a different solution to the problem -- if I have more time later, I will try to correct your solution.

We want to solve $z^{n-1} = \bar z$. Multiply both sides by $z$ to get
$$z^n = z \bar z = \left|z\right|^2,$$
so then $\left|z^n\right| = \left|z\right|^2$, so $\left|z\right|^n = \left|z\right|^2$. If $\left|z\right| \neq 0$, then by taking logs we get
$$n \log \left|z\right| = 2 \log \left|z\right|,$$
and if $\left|z\right| \neq 1$ then $\log\left|z\right| \neq 0$, so $n = 2$ by cancellation. In this case, then we are solving $z^{2-1} = z = \bar z$, which has the entire real line as solutions.

Otherwise (if $\left|z\right| = 1$) then we want to solve $z^n = \left|z\right|^2 = 1$; here we see that $z$ must be an $n$-th root of unity.

Thus here are the possible solutions:

- If $n = 1$, then $z^{n-1} = \bar z$ if and only if $z = 1$.
- If $n = 2$, then $z^{n-1} = \bar z$ if and only if $z \in \mathbb R$.
- If $n > 2$, then $z^{n-1} = \bar z$ if and only if

  - $z = 0$, or
  - $z^n = 1$ ($z$ is an $n$-th root of unity).

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis seems to be correct as is, but you have not proven what you actually want to prove. What you have shown is that *if* $z^{n-1} = \bar z$, *then* either

- $z$ lies in a ray extending from $0 + 0i$ with angle $\theta = \frac{k\pi}{n}$, or
- $z$ has angle ("argument") $\theta = \left(k + \frac{1}{2}\right)\pi$ and distance from the origin $\left|z\right| = 1$. (Note that then $z$ must be $i$ or $-i$, since only the angle mod $2\pi$ matters.)

This is, in fact, true, but we want a converse. For example, if $n = 4$ then we may consider $z = \frac{1}{2}i$; it certainly lies on the ray from the origin with angle $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{4}$ ($k = 2$), but it is not a solution to $z^{n-1} = \bar z$, since $z^3 = -\frac{1}{8}i \neq -\frac{1}{2}i = \bar z$. What I did in my other answer is show a *bidirectional implication*: $z$ is a solution to $z^{n-1} = \bar z$ *if and only if* certain conditions apply to $z$. You proved a half of this: that *if* $z$ is a solution to $z^{n-1} = \bar z$ *then* certain conditions apply. You need the other half: *if* certain conditions apply to $z$, *then* $z$ is a solution.